# How to dynamically add a lock-screen widget

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget, android-4.2-jelly-bean, lockscreen

Google Play Music app adds a special lock-screen widget dynamically when playing music (on Jelly Bean), and removes it after exit. This widget cannot be removed manually by dragging, and when I unlock my phone, it is always the top one besides other lock-screen widget.

How to implement this special dynamic lock-screen widget? I can only find documents about regular lock-screen widget, but not for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for the same thing and found out this is done by using the RemoteControlClient, check @CommonsWare answer here [What is RemoteControlClient in Android 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12217652/what-is-remotecontrolclient-in-android-4-0)