# Android: How to interact with RemoteControlClient pre KitKat

Tags: android, media

In my project, I have implemented a RemoteController to show the album art, track info, previous, play/pause and nextbutton of the currently playing media. However, this only works in Android 4.4+, since the class RemoteController was added in API 19.

I know the information about the currently playing media is sent using a RemoteControlClient. This class was added in API 14.

Since RemoteControlClient existed long before RemoteController, there must be a way to receive the information from RemoteControlClient on versions below KitKat, I presume? I just can't find how.

I know you can get track information from MediaStore, but that is not what I'm looking for.

IN SHORT: How do I interact with RemoteControlClient on versions below KitKat?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: May be this link can be helpful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12217652/what-is-remotecontrolclient-in-android-4-0

Comment: @Tpec1j That link is about the use of the RemoteControlClient. This class is used to send information to controllers like the lockscreenwidget. I don't want to send information, I want to do the same as the lockscreenwidget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there is a way to do it, but it works with hidden and internal API. You can do it with a hidden class remotecontroldisplay.

More info here:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2401597